# SoftwareArchitecture: Service Dependency - Inject Container or concret class

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, dependency-injection, software-design

Assume the following Service classes:

```
class A {}

class B {}

class C {}
```

Now `Class A` gets a dependency on `Class B`. So i just inject `Class B`.
Later in the development my `Class A` needs `Class C` too.
(This could go on and on...)

Is it better to inject the Dependency Container to be able to use all services as needed. Or keep the service classes small by only injecting those classes i need?

Whats the best practice here, and why?

Currently i tend to inject each dependent service i need, mainly to see the dependency in one place (the DI annotation in the header).

> Please don't close as "opinion based" this questions is for best
>   Practice, this have to be a opinion, but when a majority of users have
>   the same opinion then its a best practice.

Comment: Injecting the container is called Service Locator, an anti-pattern. However, best practises *are opinions*, it doesn't make any difference if many people share the same opinion, it's still asking for opinions.

Comment: I disagree that this is just a question of opinion. There are reasons that can justify an answer here, see my answer for example.

Comment: Try over at Programmers.SE if its about best practise. Saying "don't vote to close" isn't some magic immunity spell to prevent people from closing an off-topic question.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr you do know there is a close option for "Belongs to..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise against injecting whole service container. If you do so, class dependencies get blurry (eg. you have to go through whole class code to see what dependencies this class needs) and it may lead to a mess.

Inject these dependencies you need directly. If you noticed that there are a lot dependencies in your class, it should be an alert for you that this class is doing too much (or have too many responsibilities) and you should split it (or separate responsibilities).

Answer (score 1):

Don't inject the container. This is the service locator pattern, and it is usually looked at as an anti-pattern.

Reasons:

- injecting the container couples your code to the container, which is bad because if you want to change the container you use, you have lots of classes that needs to be changed
- it also hides the dependencies your class needs: dependencies are no longer explicit. Say I want to use your class, how do I know which dependencies I need to set in the container for your class to work?
- what happens if you inject the container, and then your class gets a dependency but the dependency doesn't exist: exception

This is not just an opinion, there are good reasons justifying dependency injection over service location.

Comment: thanks for your answer. (@Opinion: i just tried to give reason for the question. such question sadly tend to be closed rather quick)

Answer (score 0):

Injecting concrete `classes` is contradictory to Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP). In you case, `class A` (relatively higher class) should not depend on `class B` (relatively lower class); both should depend on an abstraction instead. So, the abstract class or an interface which is inherited or implemented by `class B`, should be injected into `class A`. The same is true for `class A` and `class C`.

IMHO, injecting the whole Dependency Container introduces an extra overhead to the injected class. So the class should be injected with those abstractions only as needed. In order to achieve that, it is also needed to design the class accordingly from the very beginning.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the classes a b and c are not relativly lower classes, they are on the same layer of the application. (but i know what you mean)

Comment: I would like to explain about higher & lower a bit that when a class has another class instance as a field, then the container class is known as `higher` and the referenced one as `lower`. Thats it! Thanks.